# RPC: request rejected (bad origin) in Confluence Development instance

Tags: confluence

I am working on a Confluence plugin, and all of the sudden today found that I am unable to create spaces in the Confluence Development instance, the create page just loads forever:
[image]
I can browse the rest of the instance fine, including things like configuring the plugin I am working on. I was able to create pages with the same plugin yesterday.

I have created an empty plugin with `atlas-create-confluence-plugin`, and the issue still occurs there after using `atlas-run`. Looking at the console log in Chrome the issue appears to be an error: 
`RPC: request rejected (bad origin): http://5cg61629pv:1990`

This seems to indicate some sort of Cross Origin issue, but I can't trace the problem any further than that.

I have tried:

- Rebooting Chrome
- Rebooting machine
- Rebooting and rebuilding development instance
- Turning off all malware/firewall software
- Tried in Chrome, IE, Edge

I have also tried with Confluence versions 6.2.0 and 6.2.2.

I can't think of anything else to try, so any help is welcome.

Comment: are you connected on both wifi and ethernet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered a partial solution.

Turning off collaborative editing under `Confluence Administration > Administration > Collaborative editing` fixed the issue. However, I still don't know what the underlying cause is and I shouldn't need to turn this feature off.

I'll leave this marked as unsolved until I can figure that out.

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Nope, though I didn't spend much more time looking at the problem.

Comment: That’s fine. After disabling React Dev tool it fixed the problem for me.